# Oracle Sql Developer Heap Space Error, Protocol Error

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am experiencing something strange while using Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.1.14.

When I connect to a particular db and run a simple `select * from table1;` I get the result set. (Still happens regardless of the number of records in the table, which is few, however the table does contain over 170 fields)

If I try and run it a second time I get a java heap space error.

[image]

If I try and run it again it starts throwing Protocol violation errors, with a different numbered protocol error each successive run.

[image]

[image]

I have never experienced this problem with other oracle db’s, even when connecting through the same installation of SQL Developer.

The only way for me to be able to query that table again is to reconnect to the db. Other users of this same db do not experience this problem. Has anyone ever experienced this issue?

Comment: Consider not using UPPERCASE ONLY for your titles; as UPPERCASE translates to SCREAMING for many folks using the interwebs.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you [increase the JVM memory allocation](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/06/configuring-memory-usage-in-oracle-sql-developer/)?

Comment: Yes that fixed it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

you can edit sqldeveloper.conf and change the size of the heap space, by adding the following line:

```
 AddVMOption -Xmx4096M
```

Comment: Here is the full path C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\19.2.1\product.conf

Comment: i was trying to import data from .xlsx file with 1M rows to a table and i'm getting error: java heap space, after adding this line, error still occurs

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late may be that could help someone else

in the explorer enter `%appdata%`

that will bring you to your :

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\
```

Find your sql developer in my case it was:

**sqldeveloper**

Find a file named: **product.conf**

Almost at the end of the file change the line:

```
AddVMOption -Xmx800m
```

into :

```
AddVMOption -Xmx2048m
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I increased the heap size in "sqldeveloper.conf" to be 3072M --> 3GB but this didn't fix the issue.

```
AddVMOption -Xms1024M
AddVMOption -Xmx3072M
```

I found that there was another worksheet with different structure in the xlsx file I was trying to import. After deleting that extra unneeded worksheet I could import successfully. I was using MAC machine.

Final note: converting the excel file to csv and importing the later one was much faster than importing the excel file for the same data.